# C# get offset for ISO8601 date from Windows settings

Tags: c#, iso8601

I have to maximise the use of ISO8601 dates in a C# project I'm using, especially when it comes to saving dates in the database.

In the same project I am creating Outlook appointments.

```
List<string> Recipients = new List<string>();
Recipients.Add("person@place.com");

string AppointmentSubject = "test subject";

string AppointmentBody = "test body";

string AppointmentLocation = "test location"; // Where do I get a list of meeting rooms?

string Offset = GetISO8601OffsetForThisMachine();

DateTime AppointmentStart = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-07T08:00:00" + Offset);

DateTime AppointmentEnd = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-07T10:00:00" + Offset);

Boolean IsAtDesk = true;

CreateOutlookAppointment(Recipients, AppointmentLocation, AppointmentSubject, AppointmentBody, AppointmentStart, AppointmentEnd, IsAtDesk);
```

Being in UK, our offset is either +1 or +0 due to daylight saving.

Is there a way to get the offset programatically based on the Windows locale settings?

Comment: Just to be clear, I believe the ISO-8601 part is a red herring here... you're really asking "How can I find out the UTC offset at a specific local time, in a specific time zone", right? Note that in some cases that might be ambiguous or skipped - if your local time is 2016-10-30T01:30:00, that time occurs twice - and 2017-03-26T01:30:00 won't occur at all. What do you want to do in those situations?

Comment: Aside from that, `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(DateTime)` is probably what you want - or ideally, use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which would make it all rather simpler...

Comment: Couldn't you just use `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)`. Ah ... Jon beat me to it.

Comment: Now this is interesting. For; TimeSpan Offset = TimeZoneInfo.Utc.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now); Offset is 0.

Comment: ...but, TimeSpan Offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now); Offset is one hour! Brilliant. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Are you talking about equivalent times? E.g. "2016-10-30T01:30:00+01:00" == "2016-10-30T02:30:00+00:00"?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins: No, I'm talking about 2016-10-30T01:30:00+01:00 and 2016-10-30T01:30:00+00:00, both of which are valid, and both of which have the same local time, but which are at different points in time - the second of them occurs one hour after the first of them, when the clocks have gone back.

Comment: @Jon Skeet When I parse them to a DateTime in C#, they both parse to the same time.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins: Not sure what you mean by "them", but if you mean the examples I gave, they'll both parse to a local time of 2016-10-30T01:30:00, yes - but internally there should be a representation of one being later than the other... so converting to `DateTimeOffset` should restore the difference. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/. My point was more that if you *just* have  2016-10-30T01:30:00 as your input, you can't tell which of those two instants in time is actually mentioned.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry. I did in fact mean your examples. Very interesting. I'm going to enjoy reading your blog. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I recently did a bit of globetrotting on the day we gained an hour in the UK and witnessed the time on digital screen at Nottingham coach station stay at 1am for three cycles (the minutes still incremented, but would overflow instead of incrementing the hour), and then it correct itself at 3:30am after displaying 1:29am. I thought I should let you know, because it was your posts that prompted me to take extra special notice of it. Don't worry, because I don't expect you to fix it or anything lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the offset with the following:

```
public static string GetISO8601OffsetForThisMachine()
{
    string MethodResult = null;
    try
    {
        TimeSpan OffsetTimeSpan = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);

        string Offset = (OffsetTimeSpan < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "+") + OffsetTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

        MethodResult = Offset;

    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.HandleException();
    }
    return MethodResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like :

```
DateTime AppointmentStart = DateTime.Parse("2016-10-07T08:00:00").ToLocalTime();
```